# Hiding / showing element depending on if checkbox checked not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two elements and am trying to make each be visible / not visible depending on if the checkbox is checked, but nothing is happening.

Can anyone figure out why? Thanks

```
<script>
document.getElementById('cbox').onchange = function() {
if ( document.getElementById('cbox').checked === false ) {
       document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
       document.getElementById("2").style.visibility = "visible"; 
}
else{
 document.getElementById("2").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
       document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "visible"; 
}
};​
</script>



<input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-appearance:checkbox;" id="cbox">
<p style="color:black;">I agree</p>

      <tr>

<td id="1" style="background-color:#3cadd4;width:5px;"><div><a 
 style="color:white;" href="#" onclick="document['Order'].submit()">PAY1 
NOW</a> </div></td> 


<td id="2" style="background-color:#3cadd4;width:5px;"><div><a 
style="color:white;" href="#" onclick="document['Order'].submit()">PAY2 
NOW</a> </div></td>
```

Comment: `id` can't start with a number. Try changing that.

Comment: Still nothing happens

Comment: please use jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dps18hvu/

Comment: Wrap your `tr` (and also close that `tr`, I don't know if it's missing or you haven't pasted it here) with `<table>` and `</table>` and change your id to letters instead of numbers and you're good to go.

Comment: @yuriy636 in HTML5 ids can start with a number or also be just a number. This restriction was in HTML4. Just spaces are not allowed

Answer (score 1):

use **div** not **td**
,td use just in table with tr

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
 <div id="1" style="background-color:#3cadd4;width:5px;"><div><a 
     style="color:white;" href="#" onclick="document['Order'].submit()">PAY1 
    NOW</a> </div></div>
```

**see my code:** https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/XRwmvw

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML. You use a `tr` and `td` but without using a `table`. These elements should be inside a table.
Correct your HTML and everything works fine:

```js
document.getElementById('cbox').onchange = function() {
  if ( document.getElementById('cbox').checked === false ) {
    document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    document.getElementById("2").style.visibility = "visible"; 
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("2").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "visible"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-appearance:checkbox;" id="cbox">
<p style="color:black;">I agree</p>
<table>

      <tr>

<td id="1" style="background-color:#3cadd4;width:5px;"><div><a 
 style="color:white;" href="#" onclick="document['Order'].submit()">PAY1 
NOW</a> </div></td> 


<td id="2" style="background-color:#3cadd4;width:5px;"><div><a 
style="color:white;" href="#" onclick="document['Order'].submit()">PAY2 
NOW</a> </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grkuLznv/

Comment: please be sure your HTML is correct. As I showed you above, this code is working fine, otherwise update the answer with the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Because the JavaScript is not in an 'onload' handler or something, the script does not 'know' the 'cbox' id. Just put your JS code at the end of the document and it will be fine